# Rounding corners inside a mesh-like shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm new to illustrator, and attempting to round the corners of the intersections between lines on shapes like the one attached. My first issue is that I am unable to merge the shape into one. I've tried using the join tool which does nothing, and tried using the merge tool which removes my lines between the blob. The shape has been constructed using the curvature tool with a high line width and no fill on the lines between the blob.

[image]

I appreciate there might not be a solution to this problem, but if anyone could give me another suggestion on how to rebuild this shape from the beginning in a way that I can achieve my intended result that would also be great :)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking or what the problem may be. If you round corners on a +-shaped section comprised of different objects, you get a star shaped hole between the shapes. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to start with is taking all of your shapes and expanding them (incase the red lines are strokes). Once this is done ungroup everything, then just select the red shapes (lines) and go to your pathfinder and merge them. it will now be one shape.

Then go to Effect > Stylize > Round corners. select your radius for the corners and hit go. You will then see the round corners.

At this point they don't show as part of the shape. so you can go to Object > Expand Appearance to get the to add to the shape.

[image]

Comment: also if you have certain corners you dont want rounded, before you expand appearance, if you use the direct selection tool and click on a corner point a small circle shows up on the rounded corner. If you double click it will give you options for this corner to edit it, you can make the radius "0" to get rid of the rounded corner.

Comment: Fantastic answer, this was exactly what I was looking for